# SEVERE: Error filterStart , when try to deploy WAR file in Eclipse to Tomcat server

Tags: java, eclipse, tomcat, web-applications, war

I created java dynamic web application in tomcat server 7. it works fine when I run it from eclipse.

I deployed it by right click on the project and export by following export dialog to the webapp directory of tomcat installation and start the tomcat server so that I can access

```
http://localhost:8080
```

but when I try to access

```
http://localhost:8080/projectName.
```

I got below error.

```
The requested resource (/projectName/) is not available.
```

I look into `catalina.log` file. and found these lines

```
SEVERE: Error filterStart
SEVERE: Context [/projectName] startup failed due to previous errors
SEVERE: The web application [/projectName] appears to have started a thread named 
[Abandoned connection cleanup thread] but has failed to stop it. This is very
likely to create a memory leak.
```

further my application is used `struts2`. I add `struts2` jars to the `WEB-INF/lib` directory. why I can't access my application from war file?

Comment: have you put entries in server.xml of tomcat ?

Comment: did you check the war archive generated by eclipse ? you can use archive tools like 7-zip to inspect `war`s. 
Typically when you get `Context [/projectName] startup failed due to previous errors` there should be some stacktraces preceeding that message you can check that out. usually some errors in web.xml or servlet/filter/listener initialization will result in such error

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ok I figured it out my self. I searched the google for

```
SEVERE: Error filterStart
```

and found, check the `localhost_yyyy_mm_dd.log` file for more information about error.

In that file there was an error called `java.lang.UnsupportedClassVersionError`. The reason for that was my jdk and jre versions are different.

So I changed  jdk and jre versions as same level from project properties. after that I built the project and exported the project to webApp again. I restart the tomcat server again. All errors are gone.

reference : [Tomcat startup logs - SEVERE: Error filterStart how to get a stack trace?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3016808/tomcat-startup-logs-severe-error-filterstart-how-to-get-a-stack-trace)

Answer (score 4):

I think eclipse is not recognizing your project as a web app, To confirm this

Open to do open Java EE perspective on your Eclipse. If you open the project folder of your app, You should see (Deployment Descriptor)

[image]

If you don't see it, your app is not web app as far as Eclipse is concerned, I have see this in case if you imported/created a maven command line project

To fix this, select Project ==> Properties ==> Project Facets ==> make sure Dynamic Web Module check box is checked

[image]

If you do that the local tomcat server will add your app when do add remove projects.

Comment: I can see Deployment Descriptor in project folder...:)